# How do I mirror output to HDCP-compatible devices only?

Tags: android, tablet, drm, hdcp

We have a client requirement for Android Tablet application which will be used for Live Streaming to only allow HDCP compatible devices for mirroring. If non HDCP compliant device is connected application should block HDMI output mirroring.
I have gone through android developer website and see that there is a drm api which can be used for content management but was not able to determine if same can be used for checking HDCP compliant.

Any tips on how we can implement this will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For Android 4.2 and up, you can use DisplayManager.getDisplays(), then for used Display check FLAG_SECURE.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html#getDisplays()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to stream, let's say raw video, to HDCP compatible device where you will not get any benefit from HDCP?
Do you mean that you want to protect whatever you mirror using HDCP and by this way you want only HDCP compliant devices to decrypt it?
If this is the case, you should then only take care of encrypting your content with HDCP (I dunno if this is possible on android tablets). The rest will be handled itself with handshaking when there is a device connected.